# finding point P such that $PA+PB+PC $ is minimum

Tags: geometry

> Find a point $P$ such that

> $PA+PB+PC$ is minimum .

> Where $A(-5,0)$ and

> $B(5,0)$ and $C(0,2)$

Let we assume point $P$ be $(x,y)$

Then we have

$PA+PB+PC$

$\displaystyle =\sqrt{(x+5)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x-5)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}$

Now using Triangle Inequality, We have

$\displaystyle \sqrt{(x+5)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(5-x)^2+y^2}\geq \sqrt{[x+5+5-x]^2+(y-y)^2}=10$

Equality hold when $\displaystyle \frac{x+5}{5-x}=\frac{y}{y}=> x=0$

Now $\displaystyle PA+PB\geq 10=> PA+PB+\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}\geq 10+\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}\geq 10$

Equality hold when $x=0,y=2$

Can anyine please tell me is my process is right

If not then how do i solve it please help me , thanks

Comment: From the algebraic-geometry tag description: "This tag should not be used for elementary problems which involve both algebra and geometry." Please be a little more careful with the tags you apply to your questions here.

Comment: @jacky Cf. [Find the point in a triangle minimizing the sum of distances to the vertices](/q/44386), and Quora's [How do you find a point in a triangle that minimizes the sum of the distances to the vertices?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-a-point-in-a-triangle-that-minimizes-the-sum-of-the-distances-to-the-vertices).